# How to make this program more efficient?

Tags: c

How can i find how many Z numbers (Z < N) with the property (N xor Z)> N where N is 32bit number and the complexity of the program is O(log N);

This is the easy method, but i really don't get how to make it in O(log N);

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    int n;
    int z;
    int contor = 0;
    FILE* in;
    FILE *out;
    in= fopen("in.txt", "rt");
    if (in == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR!");
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        fscanf(in, "%d", &n);
        for (z = 0; z < n; z++)
        {
            if ((n ^ z) > n)
            {
                contor++;
            }
        }
    }
    out = fopen("out.txt", "wt");
    if (out == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error!");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(out, "%d", contor);
    }
    fclose(out);
    fclose(in);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i know but it's a demand to use the i/o files

Comment: may be a problem to ask in https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll give you a strong hint—not a full solution, but it should get you thinking along the right track.

The key is to think in binary. Any number in binary is going to be a 1 followed by some combination of 0 and 1 bits. For example:

```
100 = 1100100
 55 =  110111
 17 =   10001
```

XOR can be thought of as bit flipping. `N xor Z` takes all of the 1 bits in `Z` and flips the corresponding bits in `N`.

If you have a number `N` like one of the ones above, which bits can you flip and end up with a bigger number? Well, if you flip a 1 to a 0 it gets smaller. And if you flip a 0 to a 1 it gets bigger.

Take `100`. Flip a 0 to a 1 and it grows bigger:

```
100 = 1100100
108 = 1101100
```

Flip a 1 to a 0 and it shrinks:

```
100 = 1100100
 68 = 1000100
```

The solution to the problem will involve counting the 0 bits in `N`. (The answer isn't *just* the count of 0 bits, but it'll definitely use that count somehow.) Intuitively, this seems like it's on the right track—you're looking for a logarithmic solution and numbers have a logarithmic number of bits.